# Error using GSAP's scrollToPlugin with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I'm trying to use GSAP's scrollToPlugin with facebook's 'create-react-app' however I get this error -

Error in ./~/gsap/src/uncompressed/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.js Module not found: 'TweenLite'

I'm assuming this is because the plugin requires TweenLite but its file doesn't import it. I've read that I could resolve this via the webpack.config file however I don't want to eject. Does anyone know another way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since its support for modules is [broken](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS/issues/165) and it currently seems to prioritize supporting systems like RequireJS over modern bundlers like Browserify and webpack, your best course of action might be to copy the library into the `public` folder and use it as a `<script>` tag in the HTML file. Then instead of importing, you would use it with browser globals.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of discussion about this issue on their forums:

http://greensock.com/forums/topic/14873-gsap-npmwebpack-import-for-scrolltoplugin/

If you don't want to `eject` a hacky way to get this to work is deleting lines 180-185 in the `/node_modules/gsap/src/uncompressed/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.js` file.

Then you can:

```
import TweenLite from 'gsap';
import 'gsap/src/uncompressed/plugins/ScrollToPlugin';

...

TweenLite.to(something, someValue, {scrollTo: someValue})
```